# why history.push not working in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to navigate from one component to another component using `history.push('/about');`.But it is not working why ?
here is my code

http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/RamvLj?editors=1011
I am trying to move one componenet to another component on button click

```
handleClick(){
 // alert('--');
  console.log(browserHistory)
  browserHistory.push('about');
  //this.props.history.push('/about');
}
```

It is not going to next component ..I am trying to display second component

Comment: What "not working" exactly means?

Comment: It is not going to next component ..I am trying to display second component

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

I got the code working locally for me. Your routes are a little mixed up to begin with. Also your component shouldn't be returning routes in it's render function. Instead You can nest routes inside of your root '/' route and render the routes in your App component via `this.props.children`.

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      )
  }
}

class second extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return <p>second component</p>
  }
}

class first extends React.Component {
  handleClick(){
    console.log(browserHistory)
    browserHistory.push('about');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>first component</label>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>MOve to second page</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={first} />
      <Route path='about' component={second} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routes , document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: still I am facing issue

Comment: Let me know if you're having any trouble or if you have questions with the code I posted